# Radio stream recording repeat Python

Tags: python

I am having trouble with making a python script to repeat itself in 1 hour interval. 
I have searched through a number of threads but no solution seems to work in my situation.

Anyway, how can i make this script end when it reaches 60 minutes/1hour mark and then start itself again automatically.

Here is the code

```
import subprocess
import os
os.system("command")
subprocess.call(['streamripper', 'http://stream05.akaver.com/retrofm_low.ogg', '-d', './streams', '-l', '10800', '-a', ' tb$FNAME', ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call your sub-process asynchronously, using popen, so you can get a method to terminate it

```
import subprocess, time

while True: #change this to check for a quit condition
    ripper = subprocess.popen([
        'streamripper',
        'http://stream05.akaver.com/retrofm_low.ogg',
        '-d',
        './streams',
        '-l',
        '10800',
        '-a',
        ' tb$FNAME'
    ])
    time.sleep(3600) #sleep for 60 minutes
    ripper.terminate()
```

As it stands, this code will keep overwriting the file on disk. You might want to modify the filename within the loop based on a counter to prevent this.

Also note that unless streamripper does something special with `tb$FNAME`, since you are calling the process from python, the arguments are not processed by the shell, so $ variable names won't be processed, they will be taken literally.